# Crop a photo below a color with Python

Tags: colors

I have a lot of photos displaying receipts, and here are one example (the black lines don't appear on the original photos, they're just there to anonymize them):
[image]

I was wondering if, using Python, there is a way to detect the red text on the receipt, and to cut the image in half from 3 cm below the red text ?